# Making a Tumblr Theme - the horizontal scrollbar showing too much space?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to make a theme on Tumblr, and it's going well but the horizontal scroll-bar is scrolling past my sidebar and image and showing lots of blank space. I'm not sure why this is happening nor am I sure how to fix it. If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated -- example of what is going wrong is [here](http://thisisatestblogtestingtesting.tumblr.com/)

Answer (score -1):

what I seen in your CSS is here:

```
webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px; 
    background-color: #faf9f8;
}
```

Just remove the width from this CSS block.

Comment: For more details how you want the UI of page just share the screenshot of your UI please.